# Using old Ubuntu backgrounds on 22.04?

Tags: desktop-background

So I recently updated my laptop from 20.04 to 22.04 and lost the background that I had set up, is there any command I can use to install 20.04 backgrounds on my laptop so I can continue to use the background I really liked?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the current background and select `Change Background` and then select `Add Picture` (assuming of course that you saved the old background somewhere)

Comment: only if I thought of that before hand, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install all (*or almost all*) prior Ubuntu Wallpapers release (*or older wallpapers than your current system, ie. 23.04 can have all prior releases, as can 22.04 - but 22.04 won't get 22.10 or 23.04 as they're newer than the release being ran*). You can also install other *flavors*, eg. install Xubuntu wallpapers, Ubuntu-MATE etc too, however not all *flavors* have all prior releases available (eg. Lubuntu keep only specific images; some *flavors* keep only LTS releases etc).

eg. if you scroll through this list

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=wallpapers-focal&searchon=names

you'll quickly see `ubuntu-wallpapers-focal` pacakged for all later releases, as well as other *flavors* of Ubuntu too.

Depending on your setup, when you *release-upgrade* to a newer release, you may remain on the same wallpaper OR auto-change to the newer wallpaper of your newer release. It'll depend on your settings (inc. did you change anything; if you didn't it's more likely to auto-upgrade to the newer wallpaper for most *flavors*).

In most cases, your prior wallpapers will still exist on your local system anyway, so changing to it will undo the upgraded change (*this will match the other already provided answer*) but there are cases where this will not occur too.  I've focused this answer on how to re-install if you're unlucky and they didn't survive, or for later readers who remember an older wallpaper they don't have due to later install (*it's a great feature for those of us who love wallpapers!*)